# Django: how to highlight groups in a `SelectField`?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I have a list of jobs, each being part of a group:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    group = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
```

How can I display a `SelectField`, in which groups appear highlighted and corresponding jobs are listed below?

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878369/in-django-form-custom-selectfield-and-selectmultiplefield) this post which my be a first step, but I would like more details.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to think about making `group` a `ForeignKey` to a `Group` model, but with the model given you could take advantage of the fact that Django forms' ChoiceFields [allow](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField.choices) you to [specify groups for choices](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/fields/#field-choices), which are rendered as `<optgroup>`s:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

from django import forms

from myapp.models import Job

def get_grouped_job_choices():
    choices = []
    for group, jobs in groupby(Job.objects.all().order_by('group', 'name'),
                               attrgetter('group')):
        choices.append((group, [(job.pk, job.name) for job in jobs]))
    return choices

class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    job = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_grouped_job_choices)
```

Comment: I really like the method but I have the following error: `Caught TypeError while rendering: 'function' object is not iterable` and i don't see where it comes from.

Comment: ok, this comes from the fact that you forgot the brackets in `job = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_grouped_job_choices())`

Comment: To use this in a model instead of a form you need to use an `IntegerField` and not a `CharField` (see http://osdir.com/ml/django-users/2010-05/msg00760.html) otherwise you get a "Value error"

Answer (score 1):

insin has provided a good view way of doing it.

But, there is a builtin django template tag to do just that!

You can do it using the [regroup](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#regroup) template tag.

From the docmentation,

```
{% regroup job by group as group_list %}

<ul>
{% for group in gender_list %}
    <li>{{ group.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for item in group.list %}
        <li>{{ item }} </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: nice! however I don't see how to plug this in a `ChoiceField`

Comment: You cant. You probably have to create a widget that follows same template tag ways.