# Django populate a form.ChoiceField field from a queryset and relate the choice back to the model object

Tags: python, django, django-forms, choicefield

I have a simple form:

```
class SubmissionQuickReplyForm(forms.Form):
    comment_text = forms.CharField(label='', required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':2}))
```

I want to add a [form.ChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) to the form, where the options in the ChoiceField is populated from a queryset.

```
class SubmissionQuickReplyForm(forms.Form):
        comment_text = forms.CharField(label='', required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':2}))
        choice = forms.ChoiceField(...)
```

For example, if I have:

```
q = MyChoices.Objects.all()
```

How can I populate the ChoiceField with the contents of q, so that when I am handling the results of the form in my view, I can get the object back out at the end?

```
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SubmissionQuickReplyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ch = get_object_or_404(MyChoices, pk=?)
            # How do I get my object from the choice form field?
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships) instead.

```
choice = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyChoices.objects.all())
```

And you can get by simply call `cleaned_data` like this.

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = SubmissionQuickReplyForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        ch = form.cleaned_data.get('choice')
```

Comment: should be `MyChoices.objects.all()` - objects in lowercase :)

Answer (score 13):

For ChoiceField you can use

```
choice = forms.ChoiceField(
    choices=[(choice.pk, choice) for choice in MyChoices.objects.all()]
)
```

to use it in the form init method

```
class SubmissionQuickReplyForm(forms.Form):
    comment_text = forms.CharField(
        label='', required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':2})
    )
    choice = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(SubmissionQuickReplyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

         self.fields['choice'].choices = [
             (choice.pk, choice) for choice in MyChoices.objects.all()
         ]
```

Comment: ^ Don't do this -- it will only be evaluated when the module is loaded, meaning the choices will not be updated as the data changes.

Comment: ChoiceField dosen't have a queryset , so it is a way to populate a choiceField @AdamBard

Comment: @DimitrisKougioumtzis What he's trying to say is this will be evaluated when Django boots, so the choices will be static until the server reboots. You'd want to do this in the form `__init__` instead.